# Subversion unreliable: "please update the out of date items"

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I realize that Subversion can really cause some unreliable backup this is first time happening. I have the above message and don't know what to do.

I was in Visual Studio. I move a directory under an other folder. Then I rename it.

What should I do ? I searched on Internet there doesn't seem any solution.

Comment: What did you actually do? Did you move and rename this folder using Subversion, or did you do it using non-Subversion tools?

Comment: I have RocketSVN Addin, I delete/move folder with Visual Studio IDE as usual.

Comment: Related Post or issue from the same user? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620877/subversion-you-are-trying-to-commit-files-from-several-subversion-working-copies

Answer (score 0):

Drop into the shell.  Try `svn update` from the top level.  If that works, do an `svn status` and look for files labelled with 'C' (for 'conflict').  If you see those, do a `svn resolve --accept working <filename>` for each file in conflict.  Then see if you can do what you expect.