# subversion "you are trying to commit files from several subversion working copies"

Tags: svn

Subversion has very strange behavior when moving/deleting folder. I had this error
[Subversion unreliable: "please update the out of date items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619761/subversion-unreliable-please-update-the-out-of-date-items)

and now this one. How to solve this ?

Comment: did you try updating on your working copy root?

Comment: If I do I would lose my work no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used the operating systems move or delete functions? If so, that could also produce the errors you see above.  When moving files or deleting files in Subversion working copies, you should always use the svn commands (`svn move`, `svn delete`) rather than the operating system's.

When moving directories inside working copies or from one working copy to another, you could have copied the .svn directory, which will cause the "several Subversion working copies" message.

Comment: I'm doing it Visual Studio. Sometimes seems to work sometimes not. Seems heavy for me to use svn move and svn delete but will try.

Comment: Take a look at the VisualSVN or Ankhsvn plugins for Visual Studio.  Should take some of the heavy of out of the process to use Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used the `svn switch` command?  It sounds like you have multiple revisions or multiple branches in the same tree and are trying to commit them all simultaneously.  What is the result of using `svn status` in the root of your current repository?

Comment: I don't have multiple revisions, I had this error only after renaming and moving folder. So the error message doesn't correspond to reality.