# subversion "you are trying to commit files from several subversion working copies"

Tags: visual-studio, svn, collabnet

I'm getting the above message when I try and commit my code to subversion.

[I saw the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620877/subversion-you-are-trying-to-commit-files-from-several-subversion-working-copies) which explains what caused the problem - and yes, I did delete a folder in explorer. Trouble is, I don't see what the fix is?

Any takers?

Thanks in advance!

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd copied in a folder (styles folder, with CSS files) from another project. Obviously copied the SVN file by mistake.

Easiest thing for me was to delete, and re-add the folder/file without the svn ... and then add to svn afterwards. This fixed it.

Subversion's great... sometimes (and that is *only sometimes* ) I wish it wasn't integrated into Explorer!